# Python string split combination

Tags: python, string, combinations

I have a string like `123[4-6][1-2]` and I would like a function that gives me list with all combinations:

```
['12341', '12342', '12351', '12352', '12361', '12362']
```

The input string can be a value like `[12-45]888[1-2]76[0-9]` and I would like the function in Python to give me the list with all combinations.

Comment: @Woot4Moo ... posting on here.

Comment: @Leb har har, I was looking for a code snippet of what was attempted and failed to work properly.

Comment: You should be able to do it with basic python skills in 12 lines, and no external imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex to find ranges and `itertools.product` to find all possibilities.

```
import re
from itertools import product

def getranges(s):
    for a, b in re.findall(r"\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]", s):
        yield range(int(a), int(b)+1)

def strcombs(s):
    for r in product(*getranges(s)):
        it = iter(str(i) for i in r)
        yield re.sub(r"\[\d+-\d+\]", lambda _: next(it), s)

s = "123[4-6][1-2]"
print(list(strcombs(s)))    # ['12341', '12342', '12351', '12352', '12361', '12362']
```